# Usage of "an/nach/anhand etwas erkennen"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, preposition

> Ich kann meine Freunde **nach** ihren Stimmen erkennen.
>
> Ich kann meine Freunde **anhand** der Stimmen erkennen.
>
> Ich kann meine Freunde **an** den Stimmen erkennen.

Haben die Präpositionen dieselbe Bedeutung? Welche Präposition verwendet man gängiger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ich kann meine Freunde nach ihren Stimmen erkennen.

--> Falsch

> Ich kann meine Freunde anhand der Stimmen erkennen.
>
> Ich kann meine Freunde an den Stimmen erkennen.

--> beides korrekt.

Ich würde auch sagen, "anhand" ist die schönere Variante, die leider immer weniger benutzt wird. In einer normalen Konversation würde wohl eher "an" verwendet werden.